# How to dynamically naming struct items in golang?

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I'm using redigo and ScanStruct is very useful. However it's obvious I'm trying to input urlhost and urlreq and these values are dynamically generated based on the actual uri of the user.

Obviously the code below doesn't work so how do I achieve what I want by being able to dynamically naming my struct so I can ScanStruct properly?

```
   func GetInfo(urlhost string, urlreq string) {


    type qwInfo struct {
         "s"+urlreq int
         "c"+urlreq []byte
         "t"+urlreq int
    }

    var QwInfo qwInfo

    c := pool.Get()
    defer c.Close()

    values, _ := redis.Values(c.Do("HMGET", urlhost, "s"+urlreq, "c"+urlreq, "t"+urlreq))

    redis.ScanStruct(values, &QwInfo);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesn't work like that :)

Comment: Wait so are you saying the redis keys are per-urlreq? The struct you scan into can have set keynames, maybe you could add a field to keep the urlreq value and use it for whatever you need to do later (presumably something like marshalling to JSON)

Comment: Struct fields are defined at compile time, not at runtime. Perhaps you should use a map instead.

Comment: yes I think probably a map is the appropriate data structure for this

Comment: can anyone give me a solution for a map that i can ScanStruct into?

Comment: @JohnDoe you might need to see my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way, go behave
you should use reflection instead

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(qwInfo).Elem().FieldByName(field)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three available functions for scanning purpose on the redigo library: `Scan()`, `ScanSlice()`, `ScanStruct()`.

The `ScanStruct()` cannot be used in your case because struct scheme need to be explicitly defined on compile time, it cannot be dynamic.

Use `Scan()` instead. Create some variables to retrieve the values, then after scanning process is done, put all of those variables into one `map` object.

Example:

```
c := pool.Get()
defer c.Close()

values, _ := redis.Values(c.Do("HMGET", urlhost, "s"+urlreq, "c"+urlreq, "t"+urlreq))

var s int = -1
var c []byte
var t int = -1
redis.Scan(values, &s, &c, &t))

qwInfo := map[string]interface{}{
    "s"+urlreq: s,
    "c"+urlreq: c,
    "t"+urlreq: t,
}
```